# Как получить ключи?

Tags: ssl, css

Хочу использовать WebSocket SSL (wss://)

Откуда взять ключи для сервера и клиента? Они нужны для локальной сети, сертифицировать через стороннюю организацию их не надо, я своему ключу доверяю. Как их сгенерировать?

Comment: @helpforprogrammer, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

https://www.openssl.org/docs/HOWTO/keys.txt

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out privkey.pem 2048
```